# Can I force an Android device to be marked as compliant in Intune?

Tags: android, office365, azure, intune

I have a few Samsung mobile phones that suddenly went into "non-compliant" state in Intune.

After a bit of digging, I found [the following article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/intune-customer-success/known-issue-samsung-devices-are-noncompliant-after-restart-or/ba-p/2952544#:%7E:text=11%20and%20later.-,To%20work%20around%20the%20issue%2C%20users%20need%20to%20unlock%20the,corporate%20resources%20should%20be%20restored.) that states:

> We are aware of an issue where some Samsung devices show as noncompliant after an automatic restart or after a managed update is applied.

I also found similar issues in [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Intune/comments/qalo2p/intune_is_still_causing_issues_for_android_users/).

Whenever I try to access company ressources from the Samsung devices, or re-sync their state through the company portal, they always show the following error:

> your digit password needs to be at least 6 digits long

However, funny thing is: They all have a password exactly 6 digits or longer.

Also:

- I did not have any device compliance or conditional access policy in use (Can't even use conditional access, I don't have Azure AD Premium)
- I have nothing else configured in Intune anywhere that could somehow affect Android devices
- I now *tried* some suggestions of the reddit thread, e.g setting up a device compliance policy that simply states they need at least a numeric password to be compliant
- I also deleted all affected phones from Intune and tried to re-add them, did also not work
- A simple device sync in company portal also does not help

What I would like to know now:

1. Is there a way to force overwrite the compliance state of a device? Can I tell intune to mark it as compliant even though it wants to mark it as non compliant?
2. In the end I just want my users to be able to use Microsoft Teams on their mobile. Can I somehow bypass Intune and the company portal? For now I don't care If I can't really control the device, I just need them to be able to use Teams. On my OnePlus Phone I was able to use Teams without the company portal, on Samsung phones it does not seem to be possible

Thanks for any help on this issue. Here's a picture from Intune where you see some Information about the devices

[image: non compliant devices]

Comment: You can push policies to noncompliant devices too. You can state which of the compliancy rules to follow and which to ignore. Although you don't force a device to be compliant, in essence this is better because it can still fail on other issues that could be more serious.

Comment: @LPChip I never really worked with Intune before. Is there a policy that says "you are allowed to use teams, outlook etc. on your mobile"? where can I find this?

Comment: We work with Intune here at work, but I'm not a specialist myself either. My colleague is and I've watched him troubleshoot some. I know that some compliancies can be ignored, but other than that, dunno. But this is an X-Y problem afterall. You have a problem, came up with a solution, but it turns out that its not the right solution to begin with. I would suggest to create a new question with: I want to run teams/outlook/etc but it fails because of pin compliancy. How to bypass?

Comment: An article from 2021 is unlikely to be relevant in 2023.